# Is there a way to find item and scroll to that viewholder using PagingDataAdapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, android-paging

I'm using Android Paging Library 3. Is there a way to find item and scroll to that viewholder using PagingDataAdapter? As I'm not able to access the item list. Or I have no choice but have to use normal list adapter?

Answer (score 7):

The next version of paging (3.0.0-alpha04) will add `.peek(index)` and `.snapshot()` APIs to allow presented item access post-transformations of loaded data.

In the meantime the workaround is to use `PagingDataAdapter.getItem()` but this is suboptimal because it triggers page fetch.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for the response! Hope it releases soon.

Comment: This is out now!